# Should a DAO class serve 2 purposes in a java server (JDBC)?

Tags: java, jdbc, data-access-object

I'm trying to create a dummy Social media project in Java using JDBC. I have a `post` table in mySQL, and `Post` and `PostDAO` classes in Java.

The `Post` class will have basic fields like `title`, `text`, `posted_on`. When the user wants the list of all posts, the `PostDAO` will execute a query, create `Post` objects by using above fields and then insert them into a list and return.

```java
public class Post {
    private String title;
    private String text;
    private LocalDateTime posted_on;
}
```

But the problem is that I want the user to be able to choose a `Post` and then see more details about the `Post`.
I want to add more fields like `editable`, `deletable`, and `comments`. The fields like `editable` and `deletable` will also have some logics because they should be set to 'true' only when they are accessed by the owner.

Should I create a new class the old `Post` class to store this more detailed Post, or should I just expand the existing one?

```java
public class Post {
    private String title;
    private String text;
    private LocalDateTime posted_on;
    private boolean editable;
    private boolean deletable;
    private List<Comment> comments;
}
```

Will it become bad code if I expand like this? There are also more details that I want to add.

Comment: I see no problem if you expand it. `editable`, `deletable` are properties of the `Post`. They don't change its nature (it's still a `Post`) and the physical nature of the device where you intend to write them.